# Append input value to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone show me how to take an input value and append it to a div once the user clicks on an Add link?

This is the best I could do.
HTML:

```
<div id="customUtility-container"></div>
<a href="#" id="addUtility">Add</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
                var addDiv = $('#customUtility-container');
                var i = $('#customUtility-container').size() + 1;

                $('#addUtility').live('click', function() {
                        $('#customUtility').val().appendTo(addDiv);
                        $('<p><label for="customUtility-container"><input type="text" id="customUtility" size="20" name="customUtility_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="" /></label> <a href="#" id="removeUtility">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
                        i++;
                        return false;
                });

                $('#removeUtility').live('click', function() {
                        if( i > 2 ) {
                                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                                i--;
                        }
                        return false;
                });
```

This creates another input field however; I just want to have one input box, have the user click Add, then it takes that value, puts it into the list, and clears the input box so the user can add something else again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping everything and redoing it:

```
$(function() {
                var i = $('#customUtility-container').size() + 1;
                $("#addUtility").on("click", function() {
                    $("#customUtility-container").append('<div id ="customUtility_' + i +' " name="customUtility_' + i +' ">'+ $("#customUtility").val() + '<a href="#customUtility-container" id="removeUtility">Remove</a></div>');
                });

                $('#removeUtility').live('click', function() { $(this).closest('div').remove();
                                                i--;
                });     
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery's [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function

```
addDiv.append($('#customUtility').val());
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/g8JdF/).

---

**Warning: opinion below**

When creating a variable to store a jQuery object, I think it's helpful to prefix the variable with `$`. This way, you know that you're working with a jQuery object. It also makes it easier for those coming behind you to recognize what you're doing:

```
var $addDiv = $('#customUtility-container');
$addDiv.append($('#customUtility').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
addDiv.html(addDiv.html() + whateveryouwanttoadd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addDiv.append($('#customUtility').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#customUtility').val().appendTo(addDiv);
```

To

```
addDiv.append($('#customUtility').val());
```

`val()` method gives the value of the input element and you cannot call a jQuery method on a string which will throw an error.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/t9D8R/